# Why pg setTypeParser is not working in node.js lambda function to get rid of timestamp for a date-type column in PostgresQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda

This code works as expected - pg gets rid of 'timestamp' part for a date-type in Postgresql.

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const pg = require('pg');
pg.types.setTypeParser(1082,value=>value);

// Connection information
const connectionString = 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres';

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({
connectionString: connectionString
});

// Connect to the PostgreSQL server
client.connect()
.then(() => {
console.log('Connected to the database');
// For example:
 client.query('SELECT * FROM test.testy', (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
   console.error('Error executing query', err);
 } else {
    console.log('Query result:', res.rows);
  }
 });

})
.catch(err => {
console.error('Error connecting to the database', err);
});
```

So I have added pg.types.setTypeParser(1082,value=>value); to my lambda Node.js function. I have written like this

```
const pg = require('pg');

pg.types.setTypeParser(1082, function(stringValue) {
return stringValue;  //1082 for date type
});

async function query (q, secret, values = []) {
const pool = new pg.Pool({
  user: secret.username,
  host: secret.host,
  database: secret.dbname,
  password: secret.password,
  port: secret.port,
});

if (typeof q === 'string' || q instanceof String) {
  q = [q];
}

const client = await pool.connect();
let res;
try {
    await client.query('BEGIN');
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
          const qstring = q[i];
          if (values === []) {
            res = await client.query(qstring);
          }
          else {
            res = await client.query(qstring, values[i]);
          }
        }
        await client.query('COMMIT');
    } catch (err) {
        await client.query('ROLLBACK');
        throw err;
    }
} finally {
    client.release();
}
return res;
};

exports.query = query;
```

when I check the logs from CloudWatch, unfortunately date has its timestamp part

date_of_birth: 1991-02-28T00:00:00.000Z,

(I expected only '1991-02-28')

What am I doing wrong? Please help, beginner level in Node.js